# What is $\langle 30,-12,4 \rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

What is $\langle 30,-12,4 \rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}$?

My thoughts are that is is all integers of the form $30x+4y$ where $x,y\in \Bbb{Z}$. I think this because by definition of $\langle \cdot\rangle$ we have it is the smallest subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ containing $30,-12,4$ thus it must contain all integer multiples of $30,-12,4$ but since we have $-12=4\times-3$ then the $-12$ becomes redundant.

Is this the correct answer/interpretation of the problem? If not where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's the right direction.  Now think about what integers can be written in the form you describe.  In particular, think about $x=1$ and $y=-7$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try to show that $2\in \langle 30,-12,4\rangle$ and that no odd number is contained.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$
\langle a,b\rangle=\langle\gcd(a,b)\rangle
$$
$$
\langle a,b,c\rangle=\langle\gcd(a,b,c)\rangle
$$
etc. In particular $\langle 30,-12,4\rangle=\langle 2\rangle$